# Closing two JDialogs at the same time

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowlistener

Let's suppose two JDialogs, j1 and j2, and I need j2 to be closed when I hit the "X" button on the j1.

I tried to implement WindowListener on j1, and I used `j2.dispose()` in the `windowClosing()` and the `windowClosed()` methods but it didn't work.

Is it possible to put an actionPerformed on the "X" button for example? or is it possible to do it using a windowListener and how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652821/java-listener-on-dialog-close) can help.

Comment: `I tried to implement WindowListener on j1, and I used j2.dispose() in the windowClosing() and the windowClosed() methods but it didn't work.` That is the correct approach. The code should be implemented in windowClosing().  If you need more help (after reading the suggestions already given) then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you forgot to add your `WindowListener`.  Put a `System.out.println` in your `WindowListener` methods to see if they're actually being called.

Here's a working example of what you describe:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JDialog jd1 = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Dialog 1", false);
        jd1.setVisible(true);

        JDialog jd2 = new JDialog((JFrame) null, "Dialog 2", false);
        jd2.setVisible(true);
        jd2.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                jd1.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, now I am going to read about the WindowAdapter since it is new for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to put an actionPerformed on the "X" button for example?

Check out my answer in this posting: [Associate predefined action to close button Java JDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25786904/associate-predefined-action-to-close-button-java-jdialog/25791730#25791730)

Comment: I guess your solution works two, thank you for it, and i will keep it in mind in case i'd need it in the future. But for now i will use Whiskeyspider's solution since it's less complicated.